# What conditions would favor human powered energy sources?

Tags: humans, energy

Or in other words, imagine a society that generated all its electricity themselves (or possibly animals). Or kind of like steampunk, but replace steam with people exerting themselves. Why? What is a believable explanation?

So far I can think of two scenarios that are kind of obvious that fit our world.

1. they are cavemen. they haven't figured out how to harness cheaper
   energy sources or how to use electricity.
2. they are super "green" minded. they all care so much about
   conserving fossil fuels and what not that they would rather spend an
   hour or two each day generating electricity on some electro-magnet
   bike thing. Or those who don't have time will pay enough money for
   someone else to do it (but are definitely not willing to pay for
   other less green more cheap energy sources. And the person hired is
   definitely not willing to make his/her own job easier by powering
   the generator with anything less green than him/herself).

So assuming people who internally (preferences, knowledge) match our societies even better, what scenarios might cause human power to be the by far most widely used energy?

*edit: The best answer would be one that is most likely to happen on earth.

Comment: This feels a bit on the broader side.There can be many reasons for that. Do you have any way to see which answer would be the best?

Comment: Generating electricity by means of a food -> human -> generator -> is terribly inefficient.  You'll get much more electricity for a given amount of food by burning it directly.  A *rational* "super green minded" individual would use conventional high efficiency power generation systems but just impose self-control to limit their use of it.  I will grant that there are very few extreme "super green minded" individuals that I've ever met that are also rational.

Comment: I think the broadness is OK as long as a means of determining the best answer is provided.

Comment: Note that there are many energy sources other than fossil fuels.  Depending on your tech level, these range from firewood (which powered early steam engines) to photovoltaics.  In many cases, they're much more convenient & efficient than human power.  The only thing  I can think of that's more efficient with human power is the bicycle...

Comment: Reminds me somewhat of The Matrix

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Also reminds me of those guys marching up that "stair machine" cylinder in "Mad Max: Fury Road".

Comment: Read S.M. Stirling's _Dies the Fire_ for how this just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a world that didn't have any horses, oxen, or other large domesticable animals, and hadn't yet harnessed any widely available power sources like coal or oil, you might expect to see this.

Yes, they'd probably also develop water wheels and windmills. But those aren't very portable, so they wouldn't be useful for tasks like lanterns, land vehicle propulsion, plowing and harvesting, etc. You could see people developing household [flywheels to store energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel_energy_storage) which they recharge by mechanically pumping or pedaling.

Answer (score 0):

A world where materialistic processions are considered a wall in between people to people exchanges but where enhanced  exchanges are encouraged (think todays trend for wearables power 1000x).

**a use case:**
Instead of googling on a phablet/phone/PC, they would "think" the question, their body powered system would send to the nearest humans who may answer or pass to nearby humans and/or animals until someone has the answer and sends the answer back.

Some energy would be needed for building those enhancements but since no other consumer goods are needed very little extra energy is needed to run even though this could be a fairly hightech society.

Answer (score 0):

A world in which sources of power are not portable.

Imagine a biosphere very different from Earth.  For instance, the surface of Europa.  Both fuel and oxidizer are available for power generation but only from rare spots on the crust at which some of the liquid water can reach the surface.

The creatures living on these chemicals wants to get work done at some distance from these "food wells" but doesn't have any other means of converting that chemical energy into useful work for other things.

The "food wells" would create life oases in the middle of the barren landscape, somewhat similar to how water wells in the very arid regions create life oases in our deserts.

Answer (score 0):

There would have to be some belief system, social mechanism, or other factor related to group identity that encourages very strong collective effort in order for people to be willing to exert themselves in that way for each other and for the good of the group as a whole.

Conserving fossil fuel if you are green seems a contradiction because being green means you wouldn't use fossil fuel and therefore conserving it, which implies that it is valuable, wouldn't be an issue because it would be of little value.

Perhaps some sort of ideological standard such as craftsmanship would suffice to encourage manual labor, in other words having the quality of being handcrafted or produced by one's own hands wood imbue items with higher value and similarly any other kind of effort might be viewed in the same way. On the other hand ideas such as greed or wantonness would have to be considered undesirable and unacceptable such that any form of automation or competitive production scheme would likely not even be considered either for purposes of practicality or otherwise for personal gain.

Consider that humanity actually did function this way for tens of thousands of years, so it may be of interest to look into historical cultures, ideas and belief systems and try to develop a better understanding of their social mechanisms. When you have a conceptual framework as to how those societies functioned you can take the general principles and apply them to your society.

Primarily it was only a matter of people doing what is necessary to survive but I'm assuming that such immediate factors as surviving and finding food cooperating and so forth or less of a concern and you're given situation so it will take a little bit of creativity but it's not unrealistic to assume that the social mechanisms that were employed then would also apply even if for slightly different reasons.